# лучший способ коммуникаций с процессом

Tags: c++, процесс

Подскажите какие способы комменикации с запущенным процессом можно реализовать? Предпологается сделать запуск процесса (фоновый процесс) который бы обрабатывал постоянно определенные данные и нужно сделать нечто вроде апи для работы с ним. Думаю написать на С++. Как лучше всего это сделать ? Из того что приходит в голову, это пайп, либо memory maped files...

Comment: `QProcess` из фрейма Qt.

Comment: А без Qt ? Не хочу на нем завязываться, может в boost что то есть ?

Comment: Ну в boost скорее всего есть, просто Qt удобнее как по мне)

Comment: [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/). Клиент-серверная архитектура с передачей типизированных сообщений.

Comment: как я понимаю, используя gRPC, можно устроить общение с процессом. как через сеть, так и в пределах одной машины верно ?

Comment: Да,  gRPC сервер слушает сокет. Если порт доступен с других машин, то клиенты могут общаться с сервером через сеть. Могут и локально.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Благодарю, попробую этот способ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое популярное решение: процесс-сервер открывает сокет/порт и слушает его, процесс клиент соединяется с этим сокетом/портом и оба процесса обмениваются данными.

Ещё нужен протокол. Например HTTP: простых HTTP-серверов для C++ очень много.

Или [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/) - двоичный протокол, который позволяет описывать типы сообщений. Для специального API - отличное решение.